# How to create JAR file for code using apache commons library through cmd

Tags: java, jar

My code is using the following library:

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP; 
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient; 
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;
```

It is getting successfully compiled and executed using the commands:

```
javac -classpath .;commons-net-3.1.jar Corpchoice.java
java -classpath .;commons-net-3.1.jar Corpchoice
```

But I was unable to create executable JAR file for my code through cmd. I am using following command for jar file creation

```
echo Class-Path:commons-net-3.1.jar >manifest.txt 

jar cvfm Corpchoice.jar manifest.txt *.class
```

Please help.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with _maven_? There's not a single reference to it.

Comment: You are using the wrong manifest file name. It must be named `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` See [JAR File Format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html).

Comment: Hi Robert this is the first time I am trying to create such a jar file. Could you please provide me the detail more elaborately, as I have tried to create the jar file the way you have instructed above still it is not working. Here is the command I have used                                         echo Class-Path:commons-net-3.1.jar >MANIFEST.MF  and

                                                 jar cvfm Corpchoice.jar MANIFEST.MF *.class